# Could anyone help me with Boole's Expansion Theorem?

Tags: logic

I have searched online, and none of the websites I've looked at help me understand the theorem or the proof.

Comment: Do you understand the propositional logic version - that for any propositional formula $\varphi$ and any propositional atom $p$ occurring in $\varphi$ we have that $\varphi$ is equivalent to $(p\wedge\varphi_p)\vee (\neg p\wedge\varphi_{\neg p})$, where $\varphi_p$ is the result of replacing each $p$ in $\varphi$ with "TRUE" and $\varphi_{\neg p}$ is the result of replacing each $p$ in $\varphi$ with "FALSE"?

Comment: I guess you should mention the statement of the theorem and explain what you don't understand. Otherwise your question is missing of context.